# Реализовать программу, которая проверяет строку на орфографические ошибки

Tags: c++

Помогите реализовать редактор орфографических ошибок. Программа должна запрашивать у пользователя текст, анализировать его и в случае обнаружения слов с одной орфографической ошибкой заменять его на правильное. После коррекции выдать на экран исправленный текст. Сложность возникает при проверки строки. С 1 словом программа нормально работает. А вот как проверить строку????

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void find(string);
int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
string test;
cout<<"Введите слово: ";
cin>>test;
find(test);
}
void find(string tofind)
{
ifstream dict("dictionary.txt"); //открыть словарь
if(!dict)
exit(100500); //вернуть если файл не удалось открыть
string temp; //временная переменная
//пока в словаре есть слова
while(dict>>temp)
// сравнивать их с строкой для поиска
// и если найдено совпадение то вывести уведомление и прекратить поиск
if (temp==tofind)
{
cout<<"\nСлово написано правильно.\n";
return;
}
//если точного совпадения слов не найдено
//убрать метку конца файла и установить курсор на начало файла
dict.clear();
dict.seekg(0);
//вывести уведомление пользователю
cout<<"\nСлово написано неправильно.\n";
//пока есть слова в словаре
while(dict>>temp)
{
//если длина слова для поиска и текущего слова в словаре одинаковая
if(temp.length()==tofind.length())
{
for (int i=0;i<temp.length();i++)
{
for (int j=0;j<temp.length();j++)
{
//сделать копию слова чтобы в ней можно было
//проводить замены
string dtemp=temp;
char c=dtemp[i];
dtemp[i]=dtemp[j];
dtemp[j]=c;
//если после обмена двух букв модиф. слово из словаря
//и слово для поиска одинаковые то вывести слово на печать
if (dtemp==tofind)
cout<<"\nВозможно Вы имели в виду \""<<temp<<"\""<<endl;
break;
}
}
}
}
dict.close(); //закрыть словарь
}
```

Comment: хм, разбить строку на слова и проверить каждое слово? Склонения/спряжения все есть в словаре?

Comment: `if(!dict)` - ??

Comment: для этого нужна команда программистов и команда специалистов по языку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если для одного слова Ваша функция работает нормально, то для строки нужно: Получить строку на ввод, разбить ее на слова, запустить Вашу функцию find для каждого слова.
Самый быстрый вариант это запросить количество слов в строке и считать пословно,
таким образом мы избавляем себя от задачи парсить предложение.

```
#include <vector>   
void main()
{
  int size = 0;
  vector<string> sentence;
  cout<<"Введите количество слов в предложении: ";
  cin>>size ;
  cout<<"Введите предложение: ";
  for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
  {
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    sentence.push_back(word)
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    find(sentence[i]);
}
```

Если мне не изменяет память то можно сразу ввести все слова через пробел, а можно и по старинке через enter.